# Saving to Neo4j removing values

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am using a typical `User` -> `Role` relationship with my application.  I am taking advantage of Neo4j's ability to add metadata on the relationship through the RelationshipEntity annotation.  For some unexplained reason the Role's properties are being 'nulled' out when I persists my relationship.

Here's my User

```
public class Person {

    @GraphId Long id;

    private String name;

    @RelatedToVia(type="HAS_ROLE")
    @Fetch
    private Set<UserRoleRelationship> roles = new HashSet<UserRoleRelationship>();


    public Person() {}

    public Person(String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```

Role

```
@NodeEntity
public class Role {

    @GraphId Long id;

    private RoleType roleType;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private String roleName;

    private @Fetch Set<Privilege> defaultPrivileges;
}
```

RelationshipEntity

```
@RelationshipEntity(type="HAS_ROLE")
public class UserRoleRelationship {
    @GraphId Long id;

    @StartNode private Person person;

    @EndNode private Role role;

    private List<Privilege> privileges = new ArrayList<Privilege>();
}
```

RoleType (Used in `Role`)

```
public enum RoleType {
    ADMIN("Administrator", Arrays.asList(new Privilege(PrivilegeType.PRIV1.name()),
            new Privilege(PrivilegeType.PRIV2.name()),
            new Privilege(PrivilegeType.PRIV3.name()), 
            new Privilege(PrivilegeType.PRIV4.name()))), 

    USER("User", Arrays.asList(new Privilege(PrivilegeType.PRIV1.name()))), 

    private String name;
    private Set<Privilege> defaultPrivileges = new HashSet<Privilege>();

    private RoleType(String name, List<Privilege> privileges){
        this.name=name;
        this.defaultPrivileges=new HashSet<Privilege>(privileges);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Set<Privilege> getDefaultPrivileges() {
        return defaultPrivileges;
    }
}
```

When populating the relationship with a User and Role, all the data is set.  However when I persists it the Role's data is now null.

```
// Before Save
UserRoleRelationship [id=null, person=Person [id=26, name=TestUser, roles=1], **role=Role [id=27, roleType=ADMIN, defaultPrivileges=[PRIV4, PRIV1, PRIV2, PRIV3]]**]

// After Save
UserRoleRelationship [id=6,    person=Person [id=26, name=TestUser, roles=0], **role=Role [id=27, roleType=null, defaultPrivileges=null]**]
```

Any ideas as to why this is occurring to my Role Object?

Also, here are my Repos

```
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, String> {

    Person findByName(String name);

}

public interface RoleRepository extends CRUDRepository<Role> {

    Role findByRoleType(RoleType rt);
    Role findByRoleName(String name);
}

public interface UserRoleRepository extends CrudRepository<UserRoleRelationship, String> {}
```

Comment: The before/after you posted is the value in the debugger before and after the statement? If yes, please post the statement and follow the flow with a debugger

Comment: Yes, the before is what is looks like after I populated it.  The after is what is returned after I persist it

Comment: @Michael Hunger, any suggestions?  Looks as though it's because of `RoleType` and neo4j not recognizing it.  I just want to use it as a reference class, is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It repopulates the UserRoleRelationship after saving.

As you don't have a @Fetch annotation on neither the start nor end-node it only loads them in a shallow fashion.

I don't recommend to add @Fetch there because it can easily load your whole graph, so I'd probably use

```
template.fetch(rel.person);
template.fetch(rel.role);
```